# Queueable method is not returning the updated values in test class

Tags: trigger, queueable-interface

I have a trigger which passes the list of objects to a queueable method, the queueable method performs the DML on the related parent/child objects.

In my test class when I insert a record, the trigger is calling the queueable method. However, when I query the related object to assert, it doesn't return the updated value from the queueable.

My code is something like this

```
public class AccountTriggerhandler{
   system.enqueueJob(new enqueueJob(childRecordstoBeUpdated));
}

@isTest
public static void testMethod(){
 Test.startTest();
   Insert Account;
 Test.StopTest();
}
```

Comment: Is there more to your code? You haven't created any account records in your test to insert an account?

Comment: I have a whole set of classes, I have just posted the way it is implemented. The logs do show that the child records are being updated by queueable method but I'm not sure why the assert is returning null.

Comment: Maybe [edit] your post to include an assert line (i assume after the `stopTest`) so we know exactly what youre looking to check?

Comment: @battery.cord that was it, I feel so stupid. My assert was inside stoptest.